# Are there any standards for Claims-Based security over HTTP?

Tags: http, web-standards, claims-based-identity

I've been looking into Federated Security and Claims-Based authentication/authorization and really like what I'm seeing.

I'm also a big fan of RESTful services and prefer to avoid using SOAP and the WS-* specifications unless it's necessary.

Are there any standards for handling claims-based authentication over basic HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenID](http://openid.net/). The [Attribute Exchange](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html) specification allows the transmission of arbitrary attributes of the subject. It uses only HTTP, and works with any browser. In a similar fashion, [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) allows users to delegate access rights to selected services. [OAuth2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-11) extends the set of use cases even further.

Answer (score 2):

[SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language). This is the OASIS standard and here is the presentation that talks about [Claims Based Security with SAML](http://www.reliablesoftware.com/presentations/Claims%20Based%20Security.pdf).

Here you [find open source implementations](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/saml-open-source-implementations) to get you started.

**Over HTTP**: I have done only limited research on this topic sometime back but check out the [SAML 1.1 Profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_1.1)

I know you are not specifically interested in WS-* standards related to CBS but to provide completeness to the answer, below are the three standards that are related to CBS. More info can be [found here](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-security/industry-standards-for-sharepoint-claims-based-authentication-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: Are there any known browser implementations of SAML?

Comment: Yes look at https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/OpenSAML/Home/. I have also updated the post with open source implementations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the net you might want to take a peek at Windows Azure ACS, it's a relatively easy way to implement claims based auth, I'm pretty sure you don't need to be running on Azure to use it. It wraps OAuth, SAML etc quite nicely.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/appfabric/azure/middleware-services.aspx#AccessControl